# Play/Pause forward buttos not Working android media controller

Tags: android

Following is the code that i am using in my app. I don't know whats wrong in it anybody help me please

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity(),false);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {                  
               hideProgressDialog();     
                videoView.start();
            }
        });     
 videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me, you can try this could help you.

```
mediaControls = new MediaController(StackOverViewSample.this);      
        mViewVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        try {
            mViewVideo.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            mViewVideo.setVideoURI(my_uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mViewVideo.requestFocus();
        mViewVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mViewVideo.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have added code as it is but still its not working I am using this in a popup and android version is 5.0

Comment: Then Post your XML please, i checked this code in 5.0 too, also try with different URI,video might be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i got my problem I was using the code in a dialog i changed it to activity now its working fine i don't know what is problem with dialog